# Photoshop color effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Online I see a lot of brush collections. Sometimes they are tagged as High Resolution brushes. When you use these brushes you see "objects" appearing in the page while you draw (circles, for examples). I suppose every brush in photoshop is just a reference to a symbol that is drawn on the screen and duplicated as you move the brush. Is this always true?

Is there a way to simulate a pastel effect with the brush ([example](http://d.pr/hfUP))? I have tweaked a lot with brush presets: I changed size, dynamics, scattering, transfer, noise, but none of this options seems to change effectively the look of the stroke. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using a free specifically pastel brush: http://creativemac.digitalmedianet.com/articles/viewarticle.jsp?id=43163

first google result for "pastel brushes photoshop"

or http://bogusred.deviantart.com/art/Chalk-Brush-124521955